# UILabel not resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` within a `UITableViewCell`.

I set the text with this string:

`@"Tes blablabla\nTes blablabla\nTes blablabla\nTes blablabla\nTes blablabla\nTes blablabla\nTes blablabla"`

It should show 7 lines right? But it didn't. It only shows the first line.
I use this code at `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
[cell.lblComment setText:[commentDict objectForKey:@"comment"]];
[cell.lblComment sizeToFit];
```

What's wrong with this? I set the number of lines to 0 too..

Comment: Have you tried \r instead of \n

Comment: can't change the value of the string. I got the text from database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this second line programmatically or set it in Storyboards depending on which approach you're taking:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; 
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Comment: already did it in the storyboard. not working. I tried to log the height. It shows that the code works. The height for the label increases. But it doesn't show on the screen

Comment: Can you print the number of lines after the text is assigned to the label? For Eg: NSLog(@"num lines -> %d",labelObj.numberOfLines);